# SQL - Create SCD2 table using Master and activity Log table

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, scd2

I have two table one is Master table and second one is a activity log table which keeps all the activity log (insert,update,delete) of master table. I need to create third SCD2 type table which will be formed by using these two tables. I have created a query which updates the dates correctly, but the column values are not getting updated properly. Need some suggestions to improve the logic of my query which will give the correct output. Table details and expected output is given below for more understanding.

Master Table - MASTER

| BANK_ID | CCY_NUMB_CODE | CCY_ALPHA_CODE | ISIN_CLOSE_DATE | ISIS_CLOSE_PRICE | ISIN_STATUS | CCY_SHORT_NAME | DEL_FLAG | LAST_MAN_MDFCN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | INE079A01016 | 28-01-2000 | 148.6 | A | GLOBAL TELE 21/4/99 | Y | 23-06-2015 |

Activity Log table - AlOG

| BANK_ID | MODULE_ID | INSERT_DATE | REQUEST_DATE | USERID | TABLE_NAME | PRIMARY_KEY_BUFFER | FIELD_LABEL | ORA_FIELD_NAME | NEW_VALUE | OLD_VALUE | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 18-10-1999 | 18-10-1999 | MM | MASTER | 1,9 | null | null | null | null | NEW RECORD INSERTED |
| 1 | 6 | 18-10-1999 | 18-10-1999 | MM | MASTER | 1,9 | ISIN Status | ISIN_STATUS | A | I | UPDATED ISIN STATUS |
| 1 | 6 | 20-10-1999 | 20-10-1999 | MM | MASTER | 1,9 | ISIN Description | CCY_SHORT_NAME | GLOBAL TELE 21/4/99 | GLOBAL TELE EQ.NPP | UPDATED SHORT NAME |
| 1 | 6 | 31-01-2000 | 31-01-2000 | MM | MASTER | 1,9 | Redemption Price | ISIS_CLOSE_PRICE | 1387.77 | 540 | UPDATED CLOSE PRICE |
| 1 | 6 | 31-01-2000 | 31-01-2000 | MM | MASTER | 1,9 | Close Date | ISIN_CLOSE_DATE | 28-01-2000 | 15-10-1999 | UPDATED CLOSE DATE |
| 1 | 6 | 23-06-2015 | 23-06-2015 | MM | MASTER | 1,9 | DEL_FLAG | DEL_FLAG | Y | N | UPDATED DEL FLAG |

NOTE - PRIMARY_KEY_BUFFER is the combination of BANK_ID and CCY_NUMB_CODE

Expected Output -

| BANK_ID | CCY_NUMB_CODE | CCY_ALPHA_CODE | ISIN_CLOSE_DATE | ISIS_CLOSE_PRICE | ISIN_STATUS | CCY_SHORT_NAME | DEL_FLAG | LAST_MAN_MDFCN | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | INE079A01016 | 15-10-1999 | 540 | I | GLOBAL TELE EQ.NPP | N | 18-10-1999 | 18-10-1999 | 18-10-1999 |
| 1 | 9 | INE079A01016 | 15-10-1999 | 540 | A | GLOBAL TELE EQ.NPP | N | 18-10-1999 | 18-10-1999 | 19-10-1999 |
| 1 | 9 | INE079A01016 | 15-10-1999 | 540 | A | GLOBAL TELE 21/4/99 | N | 20-10-1999 | 20-10-1999 | 30-01-2000 |
| 1 | 9 | INE079A01016 | 28-01-2000 | 1387.77 | A | GLOBAL TELE 21/4/99 | N | 31-01-2000 | 31-01-2000 | 22-06-2015 |
| 1 | 9 | INE079A01016 | 28-01-2000 | 1387.77 | A | GLOBAL TELE 21/4/99 | Y | 23-06-2015 | 23-06-2015 | 31-12-9999 |

Below is the query I am trying with to get desire output as don't want to use MERGE or UPDATE option

```
SELECT 
    p.BANK_ID, 
    CCY_NUMB_CODE, 
    CCY_ALPHA_CODE,
    (REQUEST_DATE -1) AS ISIN_CLOSE_DATE,
    ISIN_CLOSE_PRICE, 
    REQUEST_DATE AS LAST_MAN_MDFCN, 
    REQUEST_DATE AS START_DATE,
    NEW_VALUE,
    OLD_VALUE,
    DATE_LAST_MDFCN,
    LEAD(REQUEST_DATE -1 ) OVER (PARTITION BY p.BANK_ID, p.CCY_NUMB_CODE ORDER BY REQUEST_DATE) AS END_DATE
    --ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.BANK_ID, p.CCY_NUMB_CODE ORDER BY REQUEST_DATE) AS RN
  FROM MASTER p
  LEFT JOIN ALOG l
  ON l.PRIMARY_KEY_BUFFER = p.BANK_ID ||','|| p.CCY_NUMB_CODE
    where
    TABLE_NAME = 'MASTER' AND p.BANK_ID=1 AND p.CCY_NUMB_CODE=9
    order by insert_date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
(SELECT 
    p.BANK_ID, 
    CCY_NUMB_CODE, 
    CCY_ALPHA_CODE,
    (REQUEST_DATE -1) AS ISIN_CLOSE_DATE,
    ISIN_CLOSE_PRICE, 
    REQUEST_DATE AS LAST_MAN_MDFCN, 
    REQUEST_DATE AS START_DATE,
    NEW_VALUE,
    OLD_VALUE,
    DATE_LAST_MDFCN,
    --LEAD(REQUEST_DATE -1 ) OVER (PARTITION BY p.BANK_ID, p.CCY_NUMB_CODE ORDER BY --REQUEST_DATE) AS END_DATE
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.BANK_ID, p.CCY_NUMB_CODE,REQUEST_DATE ORDER REQUEST_DATE) AS RN
  FROM MASTER p
  LEFT JOIN ALOG l
  ON l.PRIMARY_KEY_BUFFER = p.BANK_ID ||','|| p.CCY_NUMB_CODE
    where
    TABLE_NAME = 'MASTER' AND p.BANK_ID=1 AND p.CCY_NUMB_CODE=9
) x
where x.rn=1
```

Comment: you write next time what does not work. 
tell me if the answer is helpful

Comment: @SQL Learner,
does this change work?

Comment: @ максим ильин  No it didn't work , Basically I am trying  to get output  which will be in SCD2 format. everytime there will be any change in column value  it suppose to disaplay that updated value  on that perticular LAST_MAN_MDFCN date,  can you please review  the expected output table mention above to get an clear idea. my query is not dispalying the updated values from log tables into the output table.

Comment: @SQL Learner  write   version your oracle

Comment: @SQL Learner write here : query  on change data.  
I think you are not using the correct concep sdc2. https://dwgeek.com/scd-type-2-sql.html/ take example.

Comment: oracle version - 19.0.0.0.0

Comment: @ максим ильин  here I am trying to merge two tables to form third table which will represent the SCD2 type data

Comment: How command you use for merge : "union all" ?, merge ?

Comment: union or union all

Comment: add this example here with union all. we are helpers not psychics

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b484ea/25  
make an example

Comment: what do you want 'end date" ?